# VB keeping track of high and low numbers

Tags: vb.net

After running through the following program, lownum stays 0. It makes complete sense if you do not enter any negative numbers. However, what are my options to get the lowest number if all positive numbers are entered.

```
Sub Main()

    Declaring variables
    Dim number1 As Integer = 0
    Dim number2 As Integer = 0
    Dim lownum As Integer
    Dim highnum As Integer

    'For statement to run loop 10 times
    For counter As Integer = 1 To 10

        'Prompting user to enter two numbers
        Console.Write("Enter the first number: ")
        number1 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.Write("Enter the second number: ")
        number2 = Console.ReadLine

        'If statements to determine and keep track of highest and lowest number
        If number1 > number2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1 is larger " & number1)
        ElseIf number2 > number1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2 is larger " & number2)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The two numbers are equal: " & number1 & " " & number2)
        End If

        If number1 > highnum Then
            highnum = number1
        End If

        If number1 < lownum Then
            lownum = number1
        End If

        If number2 > highnum Then
            highnum = number2
        End If

        If number2 < lownum Then
            lownum = number2
        End If

    Next

    'Displaying highest and lowest numbers
    Console.WriteLine("The highest number entered was " & highnum)
    Console.WriteLine("The lowest number entered was " & lownum)

    'Prompting user for input to continue
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue: ")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't solve problems like this just by reading code. You do it by debugging, i.e. setting breakpoints, stepping through the code and examining the state at relevant steps. If you haven't debugged your code, posting here is premature. If you have debugged your code then you need to explain to us what you found, i.e. EXACTLY how and where the actual behaviour deviated from the expected behaviour. If you don't know how to debug, now is the time to learn. There are plenty of places online that explain how.

Comment: Having read your question again, I will add that you don't start with code in such cases. You start by working out what the code has to do, which means developing an algorithm, which means considering how you would do this if it was not a programming problem, e.g. with pen and paper. Almost anyone would be able to do this sort of thing manually so almost anyone can work out the steps required. Once you have the steps, writing the code becomes a whole lot easier because you know what that code has implement rather than plucking it out of the air.

Comment: I completely understand what the above program is supposed to do. I am asking what are my options to make the lownum variable something other than 0 with user input. Is my only option to initialize lownum a high number? What if the user enters all numbers above that number?

Comment: That's not a programming problem. That's a simple logic question.  Not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You testing for values being less or greater then your two starting variables of 0.

If you don't give the min/max values and don't enter values < 0 or > 0 then the values of Min/Max are NEVER set.

So you want to set these to the max allowable and min allowable values.

Change you variable declares to this with initialization of the min/max and your code should work just fine.

```
    Dim number1 As Integer = 0
    Dim number2 As Integer = 0
    Dim lownum As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
    Dim highnum As Integer = Integer.MinValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check your `counter` variable.  If it is 1, then set low and high to your values appropriately.  If it is greater than 1, then do the comparisons:

```
For counter As Integer = 1 To 10

    ' ... other code ...

    If counter = 1 Then
        lownum = Math.Min(number1, number2)
        highnum = Math.Max(number1, number2)
    Else
        lownum = Math.Min(lownum, Math.Min(number1, number2))
        highnum = Math.Max(highnum, Math.Max(number1, number2))
    End If
Next
```